# iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Launch image really necessary?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

When trying to upload a binary to App Store, I get the following response in an email:

"iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. As of May 1, all new iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must include a launch image of the appropriate size. Learn more about iPhone 5 support by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines."

Also, the status of the app is "Illegal binary".

I've read that I must include a launch image called "Default-568h@2x.png". Question is: My app was not intending to have a launch image at all. Am I really required to have a launch image now?

Comment: You've got the answer in your question... "All apps must include a launch image of the appropriate size."

Comment: I was hoping they meant that "IF you're using launch images, you need one specifically for iPhone5"... guess not.

Comment: They're definitely required.  However, as mentioned in answers below, just use a black PNG.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you must include one. Not only does the launch image give the hint to the OS about the app's iPhone 5 (4" screen) support, but launch images in general are required:

From [Apple's Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

> To enhance the user’s experience at app launch, you must provide at least one launch image. A launch image looks very similar to the first screen your app displays. iOS displays this image instantly when the user starts your app and until the app is fully ready to use. As soon as your app is ready for use, your app displays its first screen, replacing the launch placeholder image.

Furthermore:

> Generally, design a launch image that is identical to the first screen of the app.

So really, making a launch image that is about the same as the first screen of your app (e.g. if the first screen is a `UITableViewController` with a toolbar and navigation bar, perhaps the screen looks like an empty navigation bar, an empty toolbar, and an empty table view, which then suddenly all become populated as soon as your app really gets going), is the way to go for the best user experience.

If really you don't want or need this, then make the default images just be black.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as stated, as of May 1, 2013, all new apps and app updates must provide support for the new iPhone 5 4-inch display.

The way to indicate that your app supports (has been tested with) the new iPhone 5 resolution is to simply include the launch image for that device.

You can simply create a black .png image (which is what your other default launch images are anyway) that is 640 x 1136 pixels and use that as the launch image for that device.

Answer (score 1):

Simply including the new splash screen image (Default-568h@2x.png) is not enough

You must re-build your project with the iOS 6.0 SDK (or newer) - which supports iPhone 5

So if you're still using an older SDK, update your XCode in the App Store first

Comment: but what if you want to have iOS 5 app, so more people could use it? Is it possible (if yes - how?) to submit iOS 5 app to app store?

Comment: yes, it is possible. You can build with the latest SDK but still have your app support an older SDK as a minimum. It's a standard feature

Answer (score 0):

Yes. from 1st May, you can't upload application with out including Default-568h@2x.png in your application.