# When submit the app on app store status is Invalid Binary?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, launching-application

I am submitting an app on app-store and after successful submit the status is Invalid Binary. And in the mail which I have received from apple is :

iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for **iPhone 5**.

As of May 1, all new iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the `4-inch` display on **iPhone 5**.

All apps must include a launch image with the `-568h` size modifier immediately following the  portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be `PNG` files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .

lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about **iPhone 5** support and app launch images by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines and iOS App Programming Guide.

so please tell me what to do for it. I have set the `Default.png` in the app.plist in key Launch image. Now where I have to be set launch image for **iPhone 5** and with which key.

Comment: Poor research effort -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552348/iphone-5-optimization-requirement-launch-image-really-necessary

Comment: Well, I had this problem. two things, 1. check certificates  2.Upload all icon sizes if it is is universal app and launch images.

Answer (score 6):

this is what you need

Default-568h@2x.png

you need this image with the dimention 640 × 1136 pixels

Because they don't want to accept the app which not support iPhone 5.

Hope this help you.

Wayne

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think for iPhone5 they specify 640*1136 and name Default-568h@2x.png.

Comment: Opps, I saw the wrong one lol
Edited my answer :p

Comment: Its Default-568h@2x.png what is required and not Default@2x.png

Comment: So in Launch image key i'll set Default-568h@2x.png and remove old one Default.png from app.

Answer (score 3):

according to apple must three things for approval

1) you will have to add three default screen for your application

Default.png

Default@2x.png

Default-568h@2x.png (640*1136 for iphone 5)

go to Target -> summery -> lauch image and drag the image (when you are drag the image in this section then automatic add in .plist file)

see the image [image]

2)you will have to upload app by XCode 4.5 , and

3)add armv7s

Comment: Can you also explain that where I have to be set the name of these 3 launch image or there is no requirement like Launch image in app.plist except 1 Default.png?

Comment: when you are drag the image in this section then automatic add in .plist file, firstly you try