# INVALID BINARY : Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 As of May 1

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I had imported all 3 Launch Images First

```
1: 320 x 480    
2: 640 x 960 (Retina 3.5-inch)    
3: 640 x 1136 (Retina 4-inch)
```

they have the following default names that are needed:

```
1:Default.png   
2:Default@2x.png   
3:Default-568h@2x.png
```

and Get the rejection with the warning :

> iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for
>   iPhone 5. As of May 1, all new iPhone apps and app updates submitted
>   must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must include a
>   launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the
>   "basename" portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must
>   be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided
>   within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn
>   more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the iOS
>   Human Interface Guidelines and iOS App Programming Guide.

Even after adding:

```
Default-568h.png  of  size  320 x 568
```

then also get the rejection with the same Warning

Where is the  problem in launch image NAME or in SIZE

Comment: check whether all your xib supporting for iPhone 5(4 inch) also. Else you have to load it using separate .xib for 4 inch display..

Comment: Thanks for reply but Its a Game App cocos2d and there is no xib file

Comment: The size of the __Default-568h.png should be 640x1136__

Comment: see so my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786955/when-submit-the-app-on-app-store-status-is-invalid-binary/16787123#16787123

Comment: See also http://rohitdhore1612.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/air-invalid-binary-iphone-5-optimi‌​zation-requirement-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you named the large app icon is correct "Default-568h@2x.png". If you are using any background image for your app, make sure the image exists for iPhone 5.

I guess you are trying to support older versions of iPhone like 3G. Apple stopped supporting older versions of iPhone. 
To overcome this issue what you are facing, all you have to do is compile with latest SDK. Keep armv7 architecture in Project build settings. And keep deployment target >= 4.3 SDK. 
This is the fix for your issue.

Answer (score 7):

Well I have faced the same issue and found the solution by adding the default-568h@2x.png file at the root level As show in the image

[image]

And make sure you don't use image asserts for launch image, This solved my problem.

Comment: This was it, I have been through every other Google answer for this, remade all my launch images in image xcassets but these two images were just sitting in a resources folder instead of being directly at root level. After reading a similar answer a few hours ago I realise now that just being added to the project is not root level and it must be as your image shows.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are **using AIR:**
*(v3.9 at least)*

Air automatically generates the `icons` folder with this default structure and names:

```
project/icons
   │
   ├── android
   │   ├── icons
   │   └── ...
   │
   └── ios
       ├── icons
       ├── Default.png
       ├── Default@2x.png         // Should be rename to Default-568h@2x.png
       ├── Default-Landscape.png
       └── Default-Portrait.png
```

To solve this problem, **`Default@2x.png`** should be rename to **`Default-568h@2x.png`**.

Answer (score 3):

**I couldn upload my binary unitly I clicked "Use Asset Catalog" and migrated launch images & icons.**

---

[image]

---

**After that I got this screen and clicked array:**

---

[image]

---

**At the end I had to drag/drop launch images from my resource folders into blank squares:**

---

[image]

---

**After this I was finally able to publish our app.**

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the 568h file is actually in PNG format? Also make sure that you provided support for iphone 5 for all your screens? Only adding `Default-568h@2x.png` is not gaurantee for iphone 5 support. You have to check for framing of all your view for iphone 3.5" and 4" device.

You can do the framing by code or autoresizing that is other thing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see how it iPhone 5 screen(on a device or simulator)?  Try this

> Name  -  Default-568h@2x.png
>
> Size -   640 X 1136

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today and finally got it solved!

The problem originates from a localized -568h@2x Launch image.

Normally localization works well, but apparently Apple did a major screw-up with their iPhone5 optimization validation script and it isn't localization aware.

So what I did to fix it is copy any Default-568h@2x.png from one of the .lproj folders next to the lproj folders and add it to the target you are trying to compile/submit. This most likely will increase your package file by one unnecessary launch image (although compression should probably get rid of it) and will "trick" the validation script to rightfully accept your app binary.

Answer (score 1):

I get this if I am building with iOS 6 support enabled. By default it isn't enabled in Media.xcassets/LaunchImage as you can see by the unchecked box under iOS 6.0 in the attached screen grab (grey bit).

So tick that then you will see the empty slots appear as per the screenshot on the right above'iPhone Portrait 5,6'.

Now go back into your Xcode source directory and into the Launchimage.launchimage directory and drag the Dafault.png, Default@2x.png and Default-568h@2x.png images to the relevant boxes.

QED - it fixes that iTunesConnect upload issue for me every time.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check proper format of your image? It should be in .png format. Because, name which you gave for default image is correct..So, please image format.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons of Rejections , beside the launch images.

Read out the warning properly and check all the things mentioned in the warning.

Check the following link for further changes Apple has given for Application Uploading after 1st May.
[May 1 deadline for app changes](http://www.macworld.com/article/2031573/apple-sets-may-1-deadline-for-udid-iphone-5-app-changes.html)

Comment: I have write the comments that i get from itunes ,can u suggest me type of errors please

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone 5 the image size will be 640 x 1136 pixels(@2x). Try this it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As of May 1 every app needs to fully support iPhone 5. not only launch Screen but all the UI aspects of your app needs to be fully compatible with iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:

- Your iOS Deployment Target should be 4.3 or later
- Xcode should be version 4.5 or later

Answer (score 0):

If you localized launch images, you have to put launch images in every .lproj folder even if this .lproj folder was not added directly by you.

I encountered this problem. I am using appirater which provides many localizations (many .lproj folders are added into the target). However I only localized launch images for several languages I need. So my app was rejected because there were no launch images in some .lproj folders. The solution is simple. Removed unnecessary localizations or localize launch images for all languages.

There are detailed steps to resolve this issue caused by appirater on my blog. http://vinceyuan.blogspot.hk/2013/08/a-weird-reason-why-ios-app-is-rejected.html