# Xcode 6 error msg "Targeting releases prior to iOS 7.0 ..."

Tags: ios7, xcode6

How do I get rid of Asset Catalog Compiler Warning "Targeting release prior to iOS 7.0, but all launch images specify a minimum version of 7.0 or later."  I have indeed (tried to!) set 7.0 as the minimum.  What setting am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solved it?

Comment: Just change the deployment target from 6.1 to 7.1 or others

Answer (score 0):

This problem happen to you when you develop for iOS before 7

Like my Deployment Target 6

[image]

So in images.xcassets

We have two section

**AppIcon** you must Ensure that you check iOS 6.1 and Prior Sizes // the same for iPad if you target iPad

[image]

**LaunchImage** you must Ensure that you check iOS 6.1 and Prior Sizes

[image]

> Notice this also solution to people who try submit there application
>   to apple store , he will refuse deliver your app until you add this
>   images to your project

this the Error

```
 An iPhone Retina (4-inch) launch image for iOS 6.x and prior is required when targetting releases prior to 7.0.
```