# flash builder Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5, Application Loader, ERROR

Tags: iphone, air, flash-builder

I am using flash builder 4.6 , Air 18.0 on windows 7.

I am receiving this error :

> Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the  portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5' and the 'iOS App Programming Guide' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammin gGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6- S W12'.

I packed all type of style one by one Default-568h@2x.png Default.png, Default-568h@2x~iPhone.png etc but eror is not going.

what i do to remove error. I packed up images and images one by one on splashimage... default page.

Now i am confuse may be this is Air error or apple error, or my flash builder error.

please can you assit.

with regards.

Naser.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23780432/2256820), I think that's the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved. Actually Default-568h@2x.png in wrong place. i put every where then problem solve. I don't know which place it accept. I hate iphone development, development is ok but uploading and waiting time is hell. Like iphone has paradis ticket ...