# Cannot submit App IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I am newbie on ios development. Right now am trying to upload new version of my application to App store with minor change from previous version. The previous version developed on `Xcode 5`, and now for new version I using `Xcode7` with `ios9` as target.

But when I am trying to upload new version I am getting the error message as shown below.

I already found the answer here [Xcode error while validation - "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780432/xcode-error-while-validation-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5) but cannot see `Default-568h@2x.png` anywhere in my project.

[image]

Comment: see your iphone5 launch image size...it must be 320 * 568

Comment: Where can I find it my project.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WTRlq.png see this image

Comment: here you can select launch image

Comment: are you using image assets now ?

Comment: Hi I can see similar setup file in my project http://imgur.com/a6qN7CC Here do I need to set image for every device like iPad iPhone etc...

Comment: @Wain I can a file named `Images.xcassets` in my project.

Comment: and are you using launch image assets or a launch storyboard?

Comment: I am using launch image assets, you see the image in above comment.

Comment: your launch image is blank that's why give this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Either upload the binary using Xcode 6+ and then go to `Project -> Target` and tick `Required full Screen`.
2. If you wanted to do it by using Xcode 5.1.1 then create a default image for 320x568. Name of image will be "Default-568h@2x.png"

Comment: I need to do it with Xcode7, I can see the option  `Requires full screen` already checked at Project-> General-> Deployment Info.

Comment: try the second option, drag and drop "Default-568h@2x.png" into Images.xcassets.
if you don't have Images.xcassets into directory then Project -> Target 
-> app Icon and Launch Images -> Launch Images Source -> click to add.

Comment: Now you will see Images.xcassets is added to directory