# ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display

Tags: ios, iphone

We have an IOS App which we want to publish on the APP Store. The app is working fine on the testing devices etc. However when we try to Upload the app to the APP Store we are getting the following error

```
ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New 
iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display 
on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the 
Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set 
to {320, 568}.
```

This seems to be a build or Application configuration issue which we are unable to figure out.

and our launch screen is not localized.

we are building against  iOS 7.0 and we are using .xib or .storyboard

We have created a PNG file by Name Default-568h.png dimensions are (320 × 568) and placed it at two locations 1) Under Base.Iproj and 2) Under Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage

We have also added the following to our Info.Plist

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
        <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>7.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
        </array>
```

However it is still not working

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780432/xcode-error-while-validation-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5

Comment: @Code: Yes we have followed all the suggestions mentioned in the post.

Comment: Have you uploaded all supported device's images on app store? Like 4s, 5, 5s,6,6s and iPad?

Answer (score 0):

You also need @2x version with 640x1136 dimensions. Or just set minimum version to 8.0 and this error will be ignored

Comment: We have added  Default-568h@2x.png under both locations that are
1) Under Base.Iproj and
 2) Under Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage
However in the info plist file I have not added reference to  Default-568h@2x.png

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify all images added are .PNG
2. Verify those images should be at root level of your project
3. Add another splash screen with name "Default-568h@2x.png" for iPhone 5. Its size should be 640 × 1136 pixel.

Comment: We have two images both are .png with dimensions  (320 × 568) by name Default-568h.png  and we also have this dimension 640 × 1136 pixel by name Default-568h@2x.png
What do you mean by root of the project? We have added these files at 1) Under Base.Iproj and 
2) Under Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage

Comment: root means your project bundle.