# Your binary is not optimized for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I read the answers to questions similar to my question in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780432/xcode-error-while-validation-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850903/invalid-binary-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-as-of-may-1) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595482/error-uploading-app-your-binary-code-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5) but could not solve my issue.
I get the below error while trying to validate my binary with xCode 5. I sent two month ago another version of this binary and it was accepted and put on the app store. I have the proper launch images for iphone 5 & 6.

It says:

> Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320,586}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support....

As you can see this error differs from what was brought up in other questions on this topic.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer? How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you localized your launch images?

If you do, I had some problem for that and found a way to solve it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26872153/2632955