# Missing icon and storyboard files, iOS 7 and 8, Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I'm trying to submit my iOS app made with Xcode 6 using Application Loader. The app works in the simulator and in my iPhone and passes validation in Organizer. However, from the Application Loader I get errors about missing icons and storyboard files:

- Missing required icon file.
- Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5.
- Storyboard file 'Main~iphone.storyboardc' was not found.
- Storyboard file 'Main~ipad.storyboardc' was not found.

I've gone through Stackoverflow and googling, but nothing so far has helped.

[image]

I'm targeting iOS >= 7.0 so I'm not sure why I get these errors about the icon files. I have ticked off icons for iPad and iOS < 7.0 and provided all sizes of rest of the icons in Image.xcassets folders AppIcon and LaunchImage. As far as I know, I don't need to specify particular filenames as long as I'm using asset catalogs, where I just drag and drop the icon files. I also provided icons for iOS 6, but it didn't remove the error. I tried to add Default* files as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850903/invalid-binary-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5-as-of-may-1), but without luck. The last URL in the error message doesn't work. Could something be missing in info plist?

[image]

I tried to rename the storyboard file Main~iphone.storyboard to Main~iphone.storyboardc, but when I build I get the error "Interface Builder Storyboard Postprocessor Error. ibtool could not strip 'Main~iphone.storyboardc' because it is not an Interface Builder document.". For testing I removed support for iPad so I don't know why I get error about the iPad storyboard. Here is the target's the deployment info:

[image]

Comment: I think that happen becouse you make this first universal there is ipad storyboard in your project. remove iPad storyboard if app is not universal.

Comment: It was universal and as I said I removed the iPad support, but without luck. The storyboard was the same file for both as preconfigured by Xcode I think.

Comment: change storyboard name of iPhone `Main~iphone.storyboardc` to `Main.storyboardc` and make change same in your info.plist

Comment: The .storyboardc extension doesn't  build as I said. It was Main.storyboard before but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below

> going to Target -> Build Phases -> Copy bundle resources, and add the Main~iphone.storyboard file && Main~ipad.storyboard file.

Then Clean the project using **command + K** and check if there is an error or not for 3rd and 4th Point.

May be resolve like wise.

**EDITED**

Open the info.plist file for the project as source XML rather a plist, and delete

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

Comment: I have Main~iphone.storyboard in copy bundle resource, no effect. Clean & build, no effect.

Comment: @jvj do one thing remove reference of that story board and then add storyboard target.

Comment: Do you mean add storyboard back to the project with "Add files to..."? Didn't work.

Comment: I deleted those lines but after that my app doesn't work anymore since there is no storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to waste time figuring out what's wrong so I started new project from scratch and now everything works.