# My iPhone 5 app is loading as 3.5" on my iPhone 5 device in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, uistoryboard

I have developed an app using 4" storyboards and have tested the app many times before; in fact this is my third release. It has always worked perfectly fine but now, for some reason when I run the app on my device via Xcode, it is launching as a 3.5" app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has it got a 4" launch image? File names are case sensitive on the device but not simulator so that could be the case?

Comment: you need a 4in launch image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552348/iphone-5-optimization-requirement-launch-image-really-necessary

Comment: Ahh you legend! That's what it was

Comment: @Sam Budda - you should post your answer as the Answer so this question can be solved. And Omar should accept it if that's what fixed the issue.